# why the subclass inherit the parent class have wrong?

Tags: parent, subclass, extend

if inherit TrainCar that's a problem. if inherit GCompoud that's well. where is the wrong?

parent：

```
public class TrainCar extends GCompound{

    public TrainCar(double size){

        engine =  new Engine(size);
        add(engine);
        }
}
```

subclass：

```
public class Engine extends  TrainCar { 

    public Engine (double size){    //if inherit TrainCar that's a problem. 
                                    //if inherit GCompoud that's well.

        GPolygon engine = engine(size);     
        add(engine);
    }
}
```

The Boxcar inherit TrainCar that's well.

In Handout #31:

```
public class Boxcar extends TrainCar {

 public Boxcar(Color color) {
}
```

http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/courses/cs106a/handouts/30-graphical-structures.pdf

Comment: You are creating a recursive loop. When creating a new Engine it creates a new TrainCar which creates a new Engine which creates a new TrainCar which creates a new Engine...

Comment: As Jensen Somers said you are creating recursive loop. What you are trying to do specify that. Make it more clear

Comment: that's not a recursive loop.if subclass inherit GCompoud, that work. I don't know why subclass can not extend the parent.

Comment: Seems that you have some basic issues with the Java programming language - have a look at common tutorials first, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/, http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-tutorial.html or http://www.freejavaguide.com/corejava.htm.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the constructor for `TrainCar` in the constructor of `Engine`. You can do it like this:

```
public Engine (double size) {
     super(size);

    GPolygon engine = engine(size);     
    add(engine);
}
```

Comment: thank you.Input super (size); after that, the line does not display error, but after the run it's wrong.